# Solving Gdalwarp error 'too many points failed to transform' for remapping Geostationary to Lambert conformal

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, proj, gdalwarp, netcdf

I am trying to remap from Geostationary to Lambert conformal using gdalwarp.  My input data is in netcdf, and is in geographic coordinates (degrees) and I would like to output the remapped data to netcdf.  I have created a corresponding vrt file for the input netcdf data.  Gdalwarp will output the netcdf file, but the output data is all zeros and I receive the following error:

```
Creating output file that is 5120P x 5120L.
Processing input file netcdf.vrt.
ERROR 1: Too many points (441 out of 441) failed to transform,
unable to compute output bounds.
Warning 1: Unable to compute source region for output window 0,0,5120,5120, skipping.
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

I attempted the following command:

```
/usr/bin/gdalwarp -s_srs "+proj=geos +h=35785831 +lon_0=-75 +x_0=-0.151844 +y_0=0.151844 +a=6378140 +b=6356754.99999591 +units=degrees +no_defs" -t_srs "+proj=lcc +ellps=clrk66 +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +e=0.0818191910435 +lat_0=24.9999 +lon_0=-95 +lat_1=24.9999 +lat_ts=25.0001 +units=meters +no_defs" -te -1952976.3246 -828316.5944 3248431.6754 4373091.4056 -of netCDF -geoloc -overwrite -r bilinear -ts 5120 5120 netcdf.vrt out.nc
```

Can gdalwarp remap from geographic coordinates to projected or do I need to translate geographic to projected first?

Also, can gdalwarp read projection information straight from netcdf or do you NEED to write to .vrt first?

Here is what gdalinfo outputs from the input file:  (it is a GOES 13 file from CLASS)

```
Size is 512, 512
Coordinate System is `'
Metadata:
  NC_GLOBAL#Conventions=CF-1.4
  NC_GLOBAL#Satellite Sensor=G-13 IMG    
  NC_GLOBAL#Source=McIDAS Area File
Subdatasets:
  SUBDATASET_1_NAME=NETCDF:"goes13.2013.100.165517.BAND_04.nc":auditTrail
  SUBDATASET_1_DESC=[3x80] auditTrail (8-bit character)
  SUBDATASET_2_NAME=NETCDF:"goes13.2013.100.165517.BAND_04.nc":data
  SUBDATASET_2_DESC=[1x665x2036] data (32-bit floating-point)
  SUBDATASET_3_NAME=NETCDF:"goes13.2013.100.165517.BAND_04.nc":lat
  SUBDATASET_3_DESC=[665x2036] lat (32-bit floating-point)
  SUBDATASET_4_NAME=NETCDF:"goes13.2013.100.165517.BAND_04.nc":lon
  SUBDATASET_4_DESC=[665x2036] lon (32-bit floating-point)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,  512.0)
Upper Right (  512.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (  512.0,  512.0)
Center      (  256.0,  256.0)
```

And additional gdal info on the data variable:

```
Driver: netCDF/Network Common Data Format
Files: goes13.2013.100.174518.BAND_04.nc
Size is 2036, 665
Coordinate System is `'
Metadata:
  data#coordinates=lon lat
  data#long_name=0-255 Brightness Temperature
  data#type=VISR
  NC_GLOBAL#Conventions=CF-1.4
  NC_GLOBAL#Satellite Sensor=G-13 IMG    
  NC_GLOBAL#Source=McIDAS Area File
  NETCDF_DIM_EXTRA={time}
  NETCDF_DIM_time_DEF={1,4}
  NETCDF_DIM_time_VALUES=1365615900
  time#long_name=seconds since 1970-1-1 0:0:0
  time#units=seconds since 1970-1-1 0:0:0
Geolocation:
  LINE_OFFSET=0
  LINE_STEP=1
  PIXEL_OFFSET=0
  PIXEL_STEP=1
  SRS=GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9108"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
  X_BAND=1
  X_DATASET=NETCDF:"goes13.2013.100.174518.BAND_04.nc":lon
  Y_BAND=1
  Y_DATASET=NETCDF:"goes13.2013.100.174518.BAND_04.nc":lat
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,  665.0)
Upper Right ( 2036.0,    0.0)
Lower Right ( 2036.0,  665.0)
Center      ( 1018.0,  332.5)
Band 1 Block=2036x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Undefined
  NoData Value=9.96920996838686905e+36
  Metadata:
    coordinates=lon lat
    long_name=0-255 Brightness Temperature
    NETCDF_DIM_time=1365615900
    NETCDF_VARNAME=data
    type=VISR
```

Answer (score 1):

If your datasource has longitude and latitude cell values as separate subdatasets, try building a vrt file manually to reproject, as described in

[Unable to warp HDF5 files](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154339/unable-to-warp-hdf5-files) and [gdal for reprojection of VSCMO VIIRS data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/204282/gdal-for-reprojection-of-vscmo-viirs-data)

In a first step, reproject to EPSG:4326 using the subdatasets, then to whatever CRS you want.