# How to include long.vrt and lat.vrt into bt.vrt as x-dataset and y-dataset respectively, Using python?

Tags: python, gdalwarp, geolocation, vrt

I am using following code to create bt2.vrt file using python.

```
import numpy as np
import gdal
from gdalconst import *
import osr

# Function to read the original file's projection:

def GetGeoInfo(FileName):
    SourceDS = gdal.Open(FileName, GA_ReadOnly)
    xsize = SourceDS.RasterXSize
    ysize = SourceDS.RasterYSize
    GeoT = SourceDS.GetGeoTransform()
    Projection = osr.SpatialReference()
    Projection.ImportFromWkt(SourceDS.GetProjectionRef())
    DataType = SourceDS.GetRasterBand(1).DataType
    #DataType = gdal.GetDataTypeName(DataType)
    return xsize, ysize, GeoT, Projection, DataType

# Function to write a new file.


def Create_vrt(Name, Array, driver,xsize, ysize, GeoT, Projection, DataType):
    if DataType == 'UInt16':
        DataType = gdal.GDT_Float32
    NewFileName = 'bt2'+'.vrt'
    # Set nans to the original No Data Value
    # Set up the dataset
    DataSet = driver.Create( NewFileName, xsize, ysize, 1, DataType )
            # the '1' is for band 1.
    DataSet.SetGeoTransform(GeoT)
    DataSet.SetProjection( Projection.ExportToWkt() )
    # Write the array
    DataSet.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray( Array )
    return NewFileName

# Open the original file
FileName='/home/vigna/TIFFs/bt.tif'    

DataSet = gdal.Open(FileName, GA_ReadOnly)
# Get the first (and only) band.
Band = DataSet.GetRasterBand(1)
# Open as an array.
Array = Band.ReadAsArray()

# Now I do some processing on Array, it's pretty complex 
NewArray = Array
print(NewArray)

#save the new file, in the meantime I have 
xsize, ysize, GeoT, Projection, DataType = GetGeoInfo(FileName)
# Set up the vrt driver
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('VRT')

# Now turn the array into a vrt.
NewFileName = Create_vrt('bt3', NewArray, driver,  
                        xsize, ysize, GeoT, Projection, DataType)
#Create_vrt()
 print("ok")
```

bt2.vrt file created using above code is : [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYqVf.png

According to  [1]: [Unable to warp HDF5 files](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154339/unable-to-warp-hdf5-files)
I need to include lat.vrt and long.vrt as y_dataset and X_dataset respectively to perform "gdal_warp" on bt.vrt file.
How to include it using python code?